# Nav pills (bootstrap 4) active not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, nav

I trying to apply background color to the active state of the Nav Pill. Below is my HTML and CSS

```
    .nav-pills > .nav-item > .nav-link:active{
        background: red!important;
        color: white!important;
    }

  .nav-pills > .nav-item > .nav-link:hover {
      background-color: green!important;
      color:white !important;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px!important;
    }
    .nav-pills .nav-link {
        color: #46b3e6;
        border: 2px solid #eee;
        margin-left: 10px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px;
    }
```

and here is my html

```
            <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center">
              <li class=" nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="all_patients.php">All Patients</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="all_patients.php?action=vacant_bedspaces">Vacant Bedspaces</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="all_patients.php?action=free_patients">Discharged Patients</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

Or is it because my links have the same base *(all_patients.php)* ?
Thanks

Comment: It shouldn´t be a problem to have the same php file for all of them, try placing the active state in the item element: .nav-pills > .nav-item:active > .nav-link{

Comment: Thanks. Still didn't work,

Answer (score 0):

try this instead,

### Without using `!important` and `>` (direct child selector)

> **simply use** and change the **`order`** of **hover** and **active** style.

**That is , Add hover style to first then add active style**

```
.nav-pills .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color:white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px;
}
.nav-pills .nav-item .nav-link:active{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

**Live DEMO**

```css
.nav-pills .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color:white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px;
}
.nav-pills .nav-item .nav-link:active{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.nav-pills .nav-link {
  color: #46b3e6;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  margin-left: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="all_patients.php">All Patients</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="all_patients.php?action=vacant_bedspaces">Vacant Bedspaces</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="all_patients.php?action=free_patients">Discharged Patients</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you want like this @Osah Prince?